# Getting 404 with Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Finally set up my node instance running on a dedicated ip alongside my apache server. I just began setting up socket.io and everything is working well, server+client communicating. However it seems that one of the dependencies never loads:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://.../socket.io/lib/vendor/web-socket-js/WebSocketMain.swf"

Has anyone encountered this before? How do I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the variable `WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION` point to the location of WebSocketMain.swf as described in https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/blob/master/socket.io.js

Comment: Sweet, will keep it in mind for next time. Turns out I was getting the message since Firefox does not support WebSockets, chrome connected fine.

Comment: @Dmitri Farkov, yes, firefox has native WebSockets support disabled so it is trying to load the Flash WebSockets emulator (which is still better than the long-poll fallbacks).

Comment: @Kanaka: Interesting... So where is the WEB_SOCKET_SWF actually supposed to be? I have node running on it's own ip on port 80, and I have installed socket.io using npm. Thank you

Comment: Note, the variable is WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION. The path (relative to the top of the socket.io project) is lib/vendor/web-socket-js/WebSocketMain.swf. You needed to adjust depending on where you have the socket.io project installed in your web tree. For example, if you have the socket.io directory at the top of your web root, then set WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION="socket.iolib/vendor/web-socket-js/WebSocketMain.swf".